# for loop seems like won't stop breaking when looping dataSnapshot children

Tags: android, for-loop, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "750bf295-1a99-4b0f-a072-cae87d25f53e" : {
      "email" : "aa@aa.aa",
      "hotel" : {         
        "Island" : {
          "author" : "Jole",
          "comfort" : 5.0,
          "food" : 2.0,
          "latit" : 65.05243844618913,
          "longit" : -19.647914953529835,
          "name" : "Island",
          "rating" : 3.0,
          "review" : "OK nije los",
          "service" : 2.0
        },      
   },
      "password" : "aa",
      "username" : "Jole"
    },
    "8b76cd9e-6738-412d-9e55-986b1fe967f9" : {
      "email" : "oo@oo.oo",
      "hotel" : {            
        "Bologna" : {
          "author" : "oooo",
          "comfort" : 3.0,
          "food" : 3.5,
          "latit" : 44.507442,
          "longit" : 11.348376,
          "name" : "Bologna",
          "rating" : 3.3333332538604736,
          "review" : "woooooooow",
          "service" : 3.5
        },
        "Lodz" : {
          "author" : "oooo",
          "comfort" : 5.0,
          "food" : 1.5,
          "latit" : 51.759325127252225,
          "longit" : 19.455432258546352,
          "name" : "Lodz",
          "rating" : 3.3333332538604736,
          "review" : "losa hrana",
          "service" : 3.5
            }
          },
          "password" : "oooo",
          "username" : "oooo"
        }
```

First of all, this is my JSON. Now, the problem is, when i'm registering new user, I'd like to allow registration only if both username and email were never used before (or if both already exist).

I did it using MVP pattern, so when I click register button, it checks username/emai/password fields for proper length/type and if everything's ok, it calls presenter's registerNewUser method:

```
 @Override
    public void registerNewUser(String username, String email, String password) {
        interactor.checkIfUserExists(username, email, password);
    }
```

which then calls interactor's chekIfUserExists method:

```
 @Override
    public void checkIfUserExists(final String username, final String email, final String password) {
        Firebase userRef = new Firebase("https://josip-my-application.firebaseio.com/Users/");
        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if (email.equals(user.getEmail()) || username.equals(user.getUsername())) {
                        presenter.onUserAlreadyExists();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        presenter.onUserDoesNotExist(username, email, password);

                    }
                }
            }
```

when presenter's method onUserAlreadyExists is called, it just sets error messages "this username or email is already used"... and when presenter's method onUserDoesNotExist is called it calls interactors method tryToRegister() :

```
 @Override
    public void tryToRegister(final String username, final String email, final String password) {
        userRef.createUser(email, password, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap) {
                String uid = stringObjectMap.get("uid").toString();
                userRef = new Firebase("https://josip-my-application.firebaseio.com/Users/" + uid);
                userRef.setValue(createUser(username, email, password));
                presenter.onSuccess(email, username);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                presenter.onFailure();
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, the problem is in this for loop :

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if (email.equals(user.getEmail()) || username.equals(user.getUsername())) {
                        presenter.onUserAlreadyExists();
                        break;
                    } else {
                        presenter.onUserDoesNotExist(username, email, password);
                    }
```

If I try to register with existing email and Different username, it breaks the loop and calls presenter's onUserAlreadyExists method and keeps telling me that username or email is already used and new user is not created, BUT when I try to register with existing Username and non existing email, it breaks the loop, tells me that username or email is already used AND then it creates new user with existing username and non existing email... am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your if/else statement will check and trigger for each username.

In other words, if the new register doesn't have the username or email of the FIRST user in the database, it will still create a new user, then move on to the next user in the database, check, repeat, and continue until it finds a copy, then says "this username or email is already used," and only then stop.

So, to fix this, you should not call `presenter.onUserDoesNotExist(username, email, password);` until you have finishing going through each user in the snapshot and made sure none are matching.

By the way, great documentation and explanation of your issue.

Comment: Thank you Julian! :)  Yeah, that's what i thought... fixed it this way :        if(user.getUsername().equals(username) || user.getEmail().equals(email)) {
                            exists = true;
                            break;
                       } else {
                            exists = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if(exists) {
                        presenter.onUserAlreadyExists();
                    } else {
                        presenter.onUserDoesNotExist(username, email, password);
                    }

Comment: sure thing! :) If everything worked out for you, don't forget to mark this answer as correct.